# how mongodb store and manage the metadata?

Tags: mongodb, storage

how mongodb store and manage the metadata?

for example, i want to know how many field in a collection, or how many collections in a db.

i can use `show collections` to show the collections but i don't know how it store in the mongodb, as a document?

how mongodb store and manage the metadata?

for example, i want to know how many field in a collection, or how many collections in a db.

i can use `show collections` to show the collections but i don't know how it store in the mongodb, as a document?

Comment: Yes, most of such information you will find in database `config`

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores its collections on files in the data folder configured.
The format of data in collections is BSON (Binary JSON).
MongoDB is document-oriented, so each document may have different fields at all. Each document is a well-formatted JSON, then the document has metadata stored inside itself.
For example:

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5fbcec5b0f751ebbc4d46516"},
    "health":"green",
    "status":"open",
    "pri":1,
    "rep":2
}
```

You have the field's metadata stored in the document itself.
The type of field is derived like JSON is: With quotes is a string, without quotes is a number.

Internally, Date objects are stored as a signed 64-bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).
You can write a Date object using the new Date(string) method.

Comment: In fact, I want to know the metadata of collections and databases rather than documents. How can I query them?

Comment: There are no methods in the shell to query that information. In fact, the paradigm in MongoDB is the application manages the schema so, the schema information should be in your application not in your DB. If you need a fixed schema and managed by the database engine so MongoDB doesn't the right choice.

Comment: Show collections list your collections in current database. To list them from application you can use the method getCollectionNames(). Also, you can use getCollectionInfos() method that returns some information about collections like collection type, index, and options but it doesn't show you the schema because can be different on each document.